# Vue 3, Typescript: How do I pass parameters to template refs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

From Template

```html
<input v-for="i in 5" :key="i" :ref="refHandler($el, i)" />
```

From setup()

```js
const refHandler = (el: HTMLInputElement, i: number) => {
  if (el) inputs.value[i] = el;
};
```

el seems to show as null. How do I pass parameters to template refs?

Comment: https://programeasily.com/2021/05/22/template-refs-in-vue-js/

Comment: Search for the text "However ref registration"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ref` binding in the template should be a function that declares its argument as `$el` for it to be defined in your callback:

```html
                                      
<input v-for="i in 5" :key="i" :ref="$el => refHandler($el, i)" />
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-pass-args-to-ref-callback?file=src/App.vue)